# How can I correctly implement parse in a Backbone model to include collections?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model called `Member` - this contains membership data such as first name, last name, email, phone, etc. It also includes multi-valued fields that I need to keep as collections - these are `Degrees` and `Affiliations`.

The issue I am running into when calling the `fetch()` method in my model is that there's an impedance mismatch of sorts between a basic array, and the collection objects I have in my model. Since `parse` by definition is supposed to return a hash to be used in `set` rather than actually setting values, it is impossible for me to set my collections this way. For instance - if I return a JavaScript object for `Degrees` that looks something like the following: `{degrees: [{id: 1, title: "PhD"}]}`, then this converts my `degree` collection into a flat array. Here is my code:

```
window.Models.Member = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: '/api/member',

    initialize: function() {

        _.bindAll(this);

        this.set('degrees', new window.Collections.DegreesList());

        this.fetch();

    },

    parse: function(response) {

        var setHash = {};

        setHash.first_name = response.first_name;
        setHash.last_name = response.last_name;
        setHash.office_phone = response.office_phone;

        // When this is run, this.get('degrees') will now return a flat array rather than a DegreesList collection
        setHash.degrees = _(response.degrees).each(function(item) { 
                return {id: item.id, title: item.title} 
        });

        return setHash;

    }

});
```

I could manually set the collections in my parse function, but that seems like its subverting the Backbone way, and hacky.

EDIT: I've temporarily solved the problem by doing the following:

```
parse: function(response) {

    var setHash = {};

    setHash.first_name = response.first_name;
    setHash.last_name = response.last_name;
    setHash.office_phone = response.office_phone;

    this.get('degrees').reset( response.degrees );

    return setHash;     
}
```

I doubt this is the optimal solution, but it certainly works for now. I'm open to better suggestions.

Comment: Try this: ditch the `parse:` function (it doesn't seem to be needed), and instead inside `initialize:` manually transform the `degrees` attribute from an array to a Backbone collection...

Comment: `parse` gets called automatically once the `fetch` method returns. I could manually reset the `degrees` attribute back to a collection after `fetch` is called, but then I wouldn't have any of the data in that collection that I want...and data is coming in.

Comment: You would have to do a lot of thing with `degrees` if you manually add them in the `parse`. Go with @ŠimeVidas' suggestion and use a Backbone collection for them. It let you deal with each `degree` the Backbone way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use exactly the same workaround you are proposing except with a few changes.

1. To avoid misunderstanding I call the collection in the JSON: `degreesData`
2. In the `initialize` I create the collection like this: `this.degrees = new Degrees().reset( this.get( "degreesData" ) );`

Comment: Sorry for digging up old questions, but how can you get degreesData from inside initialize? Initialize runs when you instantiate the model.. degressData would not be populated until after you fetch, which you do INSIDE initialize.

Comment: @raynjamin what I populate in the initialize is the `degrees` Collection no the `degreesData` attribute. The `degreesData` attribute comes as part of the initial JSON that is used to initialize the Model, so this info is available in the `initialize()`. _(If I remember properly)_

Comment: Digging this up again, what if you need to initialize an empty model? You're going to have to start coding in defaults and stuff. Maybe parse is a better option, at least you're (almost) guaranteed to have data at that point.